# Emeralds bet - A round world

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, story

It was the 15 October 1502, just a few hours before midnight in an old tavern at the docks. Emerald raised two fingers, after repeatedly looking at his three cards, before finally answering the awaiting dealer. "Stick!" His voice was a bit shaky, since his last savings were at stake. As each player started to reveal his cards, Emerald quickly counting their points - and with 28, he was the highest so far. But this just wasn't his lucky day, and just as he revealed his cards, the dealer started to smile - revealing his 31 points.

"I can't believe it! Again!" Emerald dug his nails into his wooden chair, looking up to the dealer. "I don't have more with me. I'll pay the rest next month, alright?"

The dealer nodded, before asking with another smile "Tell ye what... I'll give ya chance ta 'win it back. With a simple lil' bet."

Emerald raised an eyebrow, "A bet?"

The dealer calmly nodded once more while reaching for the other players' cards. "Yeah. Remember that ol' bookworm th'was here earlier?"

Emerald shrugged. "The guy that blabbered about a round world?" he scratched his chin. "What about him?"

The dealer's smile turned into a greedy grin. "Prove me that th'world is a ball, and you get m'winnings. If ya can't, I get double. 'til Friday. Deal?"

Emerald had the luck to talk with the scholar from before and smiled, quickly standing up to shake the dealers hand. "Deal. But I think I can prove it to you tonight, if you still stay sober for another hour or two."

**Puzzle**

How can Emerald prove that the world is round without leaving the city? And how can he do it in the same night?

For extra fun: What's the game they're playing?

(This is my first riddle here, and I wanted to add a bit of atmosphere to it - but since I'm not a native English speaker, my writing style is probably a bit weird. ;) Still, good luck 'solving' it. It's not too hard. Also, tagging puzzles is a puzzle by itself!)

Comment: The story is delightful, and if I may say, your writing style is excellent.

Comment: @dennisdeems Thanks, I wasn't sure how it'ld turn out for others to read ;) Always difficult to judge - at least for me!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On the 15th October 1502

> there was a lunar eclipse, with the TD of greatest eclipse at 23:10:40. 
>  As the eclipse progresses, the Moon slowly moves through Earth's shadow. 
>  Every time that shadow is seen, its edge is round.  The only solid that always projects a round shadow is a sphere.

For extra fun: The game being played here is

> [Thirty-One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-one_(card_game)) (Credit to @Len) 
> Reasoning on why it could not also be a disk: [Spherical Proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39127/is-the-sphere-the-only-surface-all-of-whose-projections-are-circles-or-can-we)
> [Catalog of Lunar Eclipses](http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/LEcat5/LE1501-1600.html)

Comment: A disk will also do that, at least once.  But on the plus side, disks are also round.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to convey the fact that from any angle a sphere would always project a circular shadow - whereas if the earth was a disk, the shape of the shadow on the moon would change as it proceeded across the sky.

Comment: This is an interesting discussion on it: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39127/is-the-sphere-the-only-surface-all-of-whose-projections-are-circles-or-can-we

Comment: @alexmc - "for extra fun", the game sounds like [Thirty-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-one_(card_game)) which also has many other names.

Comment: @Len That's correct - 3 cards to start with, and then it's played similar to blackjack but with 31 instead of 21 points ;D

Comment: As a side note - I was thinking about ways to hide the date inside the conversation, but eh... that might would've made it too cryptic hehe

Comment: Thanks @Len! Haha, loving the alternative names for it - I'll have to brush up on my Nickel Nock.

Comment: @Len From reading the rules for 31, it sounds like it was incorrectly played in the riddle... if the dealer had 31 he should have turned it over immediately; otherwise, since he wasn't the lowest value he shouldn't have lost anything.

Comment: @Michael you're right, that's actually my mistake ;) I initially gave the dealer 29 points (since 31 would've been a bit cliché), but decided to change it to 31 last-minute to give another hint to the actual game (since otherwise it would have been quite vague) - so that last minute change actually created that 'inconsistency' that I didn't notice.

Comment: @Katai they're playing sailor rules. No immediate turnover, so you can still beat the dealer with a player 31, since as a player you can turnover immediately! (But you usually also lose double against a 31 from the dealer if you can't beat it)

Comment: @Falco Ha! That would actually be fitting the scenario well then, since they're sitting close to a harbor anyways and that would make the stakes even higher ;) Thanks for the info! Lucky that theese kinds of games have so many variations to them.

Comment: An eclipse at 23:10 would be hard to observe as it would be night time surely?

Comment: @SteveMatthews Its a lunar eclipse.  They seldom occur during daytime.

Comment: The mathoverflow question only discuss the fact that all projections of a sphere are circles.  This tells us that if we could see all possible shadows the earth could cast we would know that the earth is a sphere.  However we can only see a subset of those shadows, so I think a disc remain possible.  At the very least a half sphere (with the dealer and Emerald on the flat side) can not be discounted from a single lunar eclipse.

Comment: @Taemyr Technically, it's always daytime somewhere during a lunar eclipse... ;-)

Comment: @Michael Yes.  I meant it's usually nighttime for the people seeing the eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

alexmc's answer is more robust than this one, but I thought this was also a fun solution to point out. Not as mathematically sound, but also more widely applicable.

> Take the barkeep to the nearby ocean. First, take a ruler or something straight, and try to line it up with the horizon. You will be able to see that the horizon is in fact curved, with the edges lower than the middle. Then wait for a ship to either enter into sight or leave. You will notice that the first (or last) thing you see is the mast. This shows that the earth is also curved in that direction. With curvature on two perpendicular axes, you could conclude that the earth, or at least the part you are standing on, is round.

Comment: That was actually the second possibility, yes - and the reason why the tavern was close to the harbor ;D Gj

Comment: @Katai Wait, the tavern was close to the harbor solely on the off-chance that somebody would make a bet with someone else that they couldn't prove the world was round?

Comment: No--these tests work during the day.  The puzzle says this happens at night.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Actually, it's surprisingly easy to see ships on the horizon at night if you look closely. Outside of a city, at least. I think it's reasonable to assume that in 1502 light pollution isn't a problem.

Comment: @Michael Nono, what I meant was that the tavern is at a harbor, to allow for someone to bring the "sinking ship" solution as alternative to the lunar eclipse ;) - but that location was chosen with "out of world" (my) reasoning, not because anyone building the tavern thought "Hey, they could bet about round worlds in 20 years!".

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Ships these days have lights you can see.  Back then....

Comment: @LorenPechtel ...Oh, right. Though if you get lucky you might see a ship slowly stop blocking a star or (better) a nebula.